# Which algorithm should I choose and why?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, k-nn, lda

My friend was reading a textbook and had this question:

Suppose that you observe $(X_1,Y_1),...,(X_{100}Y_{100})$, which you assume to be i.i.d. copies of a random pair $(X,Y)$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{1,2\}$. Your plot the data and see the following:[image]

where black circles represent those $X_i$ with $Y_i=1$ and the red triangles represent those $X_i$ with $Y_i=2$. A practitioner tells you that their misclassification costs are equal, $c_1 = c_2 = 1$, and
would like advice on which algorithm to use for prediction. Given the options:

- Linear discriminant analysis;
- K-Nearest neighbours with $K=5$
- K-Nearest neighbours with $K=90$.

What would be the best algorithm for this? I think it should be $5$, as the bigger the $K$, the worse the accuracy gets? What would be your choice and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the optimal method using [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#:%7E:text=Cross%2Dvalidation%2C%20sometimes%20called%20rotation,to%20an%20independent%20data%20set.). If your sample size is relatively small, use *leave-one-out* cross-validation... I would not be surprised if $K = 5$ worked well. Linear discriminant analysis (LDA) will not work here because it implies linear decision boundaries. Unless you enlarge the set of predictors with non-linear transformations.

Also, the picture above is a classic case where support vector machines (SVM) with a Gaussian kernel could be of use. R has a friendly implementation of SVM in the "kernlab" package.

Comment: Hi. But why would I not use $K=90$?

Comment: I did not say you shouldn't. What I meant: use cross-validation to decide.

Comment: No, I mean my question was, given you only have this graph and you had to choose between $K=90$ or $K=5$, what would you choose? And why?

Comment: Why would you base your decision on the graph only? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: I personally wouldn't decide only based on a graph, but the question is from a textbook. It's not homework though! I'd like to hear a good explanation as to why someone would choose one algo over the other, given they only have this graph:)

Comment: $K = 5$ will work better than $K = 90$ because the two classes are relatively small in sample size. Assuming we are seeing all the data.

Comment: I see. Thank you!